# Images from my database won't align horizontally (not with float or inline-block)

Tags: php, html, css, image, gallery

I have made a database over some different cakes (my exam project in High School), and now I want to show pictures from my database in my gallery, aligned horizontally in a form of table or just so there are several images on each line.

I have looked all over the internet for several hours, and the answers I find are ways to use float:left or display:inline-block, I have tried both of these and much more, but my code wont work.

The overlay and container divs shouldn't be important for this issue, but if these are the problem please do tell. Thank you so much in advance. 
Here is a photo of my current galley, and my css plus html/php.

html/php:

```
echo"
        <div class='container'> 
                <img src='images/".$billede."' alt=".$navn." class='image'/>
                <div class='overlay'> ".$navn." ".$pris."</div>
        </div>
    ";
```

css:

```
.container {
position: relative;
width: 50%;
max-width: 300px;
}

.overlay {
 position: absolute; 
 bottom: 0; 
 background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
 color: #f1f1f1; 
 width: 100%;
 transition: .5s ease;
 opacity:0;
 color: white;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-family: "Calibri";
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

.image {
display: inline-block;
width: 300px;
height: auto;
float: left;
}
```

[Image of the current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX6Zn.png)

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle or compiled html?

Comment: remove the spaces between the <div and div> tags

Comment: Sorry Nirali, I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm not sure how to do that, and Bernhard which divs do you mean? the </div>s or the div before and after the image?